# Is it still recursion when the method is called on a difference instance?

Tags: oop, recursion, functional-programming

While preparing for my talk about functional programming, I have a simple implementation of a Linked List, where the method to get the length is like this.

```
# base class List

# class EmptyList < List
def length
  0
end

# class NonEmptyList < List
# this class has a @head and a @tail attributes
def length
  1 + @tail.length
end
```

The implementation for the `length` method of the `NonEmptyList` class looks like a recursive function. The reason I think it is not is because I call `length` on a different instance, even though that other instance is of the same class List.

Please let me know if this is recursive. Also, is there any performance issue if this solution to get the length consume too much of the call stack.

Comment: What language is this supposed to be?

Comment: It does not matter what language it is. It is Ruby btw.

Comment: It matters because you have a fragment of code in the question, and only someone familiar with Ruby will know what it means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is recursive. You should consider `this` (or the object on which a function is being invoked, regardless of the syntax) to be just like any other function parameter... a recursive function does not need to invoke itself with the exact same parameters on each recursive call to be recursive (in fact, if it did, it would never stop recursing). Similarly, here, you are doing the moral equivalent of changing the parameter to the function, that doesn't make the function any less recursive.

A function is recursive if and only if it may, in some cases, invoke itself, either directly or indirectly. The specific set of parameters (or context) in which it invokes itself is irrelevant to the definition.

Comment: Good separation of 'can' from 'does'; the late was in my comment but is a bit misleading.